# How to init socket io connection with nextjs

Tags: reactjs, sockets, websocket, next.js, socket.io

I'm really new in websockets and I have some problems and misunderstanding with socket.io-client. Also sorry for my english :)
First things first I dont understand how to connect from client to socket.

I did this, and it worked

```
useEffect(() => {
 fetch('/api/socket')
 const socket = io()
}, [])
```

But in socket io docs and some articles I saw this implementation

```
useEffect(() => {
 const socket = io('/api/socket')
}, [])
```

This approach didn't work, and my browser sent this:

*Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=N-H8vGv1-uiKmvAjAAAe.*

Also I saw some init code like: io.connect() / SocketClientIO.connect (or smth like that) but they just didnt work as well. (I think it's for old versions socket io, am I right?)

So how to do it right?

**Second question** Is it a good idea in general connect to socket io in useEffect? I know, that useEffect bad place for effects etc, but all tutorials I found made it in useEffect.

**Third question** It's connected with the second. I use nextjs with strict mode, so useEffect make double render. This is my client component

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { io, Socket } from 'socket.io-client'
import { DefaultEventsMap } from '@socket.io/component-emitter'

let socket: Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap>

const RoomPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { room } = router.query

  const leaveRoomHandler = () => {
    router.push('/rooms')
  }

  const socketInitializer = async () => {
    await fetch('/api/socket')
    socket = io()

    socket.on('user-joined', (msg) => {
      console.log(msg)
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (room) {
      socketInitializer().then(() => socket.emit('join-room', room))
    }

    return () => {
      socket?.disconnect()
    }
  }, [room])

  return (
     <>
      <h2>Room {room}</h2>
      <button onClick={leaveRoomHandler}>Leave room</button>
    </>
   )
}

export default RoomPage
```

So with this code I get some errors. When I enter the page first time I see, in server console, that 'user connected', then again 'user connected', and nothing about disconnect. Why? When I manually leave the page disconnect works well. So after that if I connect and disconnect several times to this component, I get two times more console.logs on client than last time (2, 4, 6, 8, etc).
Whats the problem with my code?)

Comment: I would also like to know...